# java.net.ConnectException when running test with Flyway and embedded Postgresql inside Docker container

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, spring-boot, flyway

In order to properly test my Spring Boot application I am using [embedded Postgresql](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded) in integration tests. Moreover I use Flyway too which is configured to use data source based on Postgresql configuration (take a look into `EmbeddedPostgresConfiguration` and `FlywayConfiguration` classes).

All my tests pass without problems when running on my environment (OS X), but they fail when being run inside Docker container (for both `java:8` and `openjdk:8` images). And I have no clue what is the reason for that difference and how to fix it to have tests passing inside Docker (it is needed for further Continuous Integration pipeline).

**Here is minimal code sample to replicate the issue: https://github.com/nkoder/postgresql-embedded-example .**

To run tests without problems run `./gradlew clean test`. To run tests with failure run `docker build .`.

Error thrown during tests run inside Docker:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
            Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException
                Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
                    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException
```

I was trying to solve this issues for my own but I still have only some guesses and nothing solid. The only "hint": for hardcoded (non-random) port used in embedded Postgresql configuration sometimes similar exception occured in line `flyway.clean();` in `FlywayConfiguration` class (when running tests from IntelliJ IDEA in real project with more tests) which seems to be first line of code which access database through provided data source.

**Update 1:** Postgresql instance is created during tests on localhost on random open port **inside** same Docker container. I suspect there is no need for connectivity to host machine (outside container).

Comment: ConnectException arises always when a proxy or firewall is blocking an output connection. Have you reviewed the internetworking configuration of Docker?

Comment: Both tests and embedded Postgresql run in same container. I mean in test there is postgresql created at `localhost:<randomOpenPort>` and it's used as data source. There is nothing reaching internet "outside" a container (or at least nothing I am aware of).

Comment: I see, but I insist: Even though the communications are kept within the same localhost, connecting to a local port may be blocked by the local firewall.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood you then and I understand now. Will check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

According to https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded we cannot use root to run embedded Postgresql in tests. Therefore what I needed to fix the problem was to run tests inside Docker as non-root user.

You can see fix here: https://github.com/nkoder/postgresql-embedded-example/commit/391977052b1563cdcabf66a2fe3ca0a3e0a7b358

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that you application is trying to reach the DB at localhost. But when it is running in a docker container localhost is the container and not the hist machine. So you'll have to change the config to make this work.

Comment: I want to connect to Docker's localhost (inside container). There is nothing on host machine that I want to connect to. There is no "external" Postgresql, only this one created during tests run, inside the same container.

Comment: How do you create a Postgres? And if there is no DB running in your Container this is why it fails.

Comment: Embedded Postgres configuration is defined in `EmbeddedPostgresConfiguration`. There is no standalone Postgres (neither in Docker nor on my local environment where tests pass_

Comment: Well but this is what I mean. Embedded Postgres is not an in JVM DB like HSQL or H2 but only a wrapper that starts a local instance as I understood the yandex site. Therefore it will just not work if you don't have Postgres installed in your container.